# $Tan A = Tan B = Tan$ C then A=B=C?

Tags: trigonometry

Please can someone help me in understaning this question.

If $Tan A = Tan B = Tan C $, then how can I prove that $A=B=C$?

Note:A,B,C are angles of triangle and need to show triangle is equilateral.

Comment: what are the variables $$A,B,C$$?

Comment: You can't without more assumptions...

Comment: $\tan(0)=\tan(\pi)=\tan(2 \pi)=0\,$.

Comment: Hint: $\tan(x)$ is injective on $(0,\pi) \setminus \{\frac{\pi}{2}\}\,$.

Comment: @ dxiv so how can I prove through injection? Can you explain a bit more, please

Comment: By definition of an injective function, $f(a)=f(b) \implies a=b\,$. Whether you know (or can prove) that $\tan(x)$ is injective on $(0,\pi)\setminus\{\frac{\pi}{2}\}$ is a different matter, and one I can't help with, since you gave no context to (and no hint of own work on) the question, so I can't guess what you *do* know about $\tan(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Algebraically, take $tan^{-1}$ of all equations.

With $f$ a function and $f^{-1}$ the inverse function of $f$: 
$$f(A)=f(B)=f(C)$$
$$f^{-1}(f(A))=f^{-1}(f(B))=f^{-1}(f(C))$$
$$f^{-1}(f(x))=x \Rightarrow A=B=C$$

In the context of a triangle, the sum of the angles must equal $\pi$ radians. No angle can be equal to any integer multiple of $\pi$ because of the range of $tan$, and must be in the real-valued set $x\in (0,\pi)$, which is the same as the range of $tan^{-1}(tan(x))$ in this context.  $\frac{\pi}{3}$ is the only angle that satisfies equality in this case.

Answer (score 1):

In a triangle $C=\pi-(A+B)$.

Let's call $t=\tan(A)=\tan(B)=\tan(C)$

$t=\tan(C)=-\tan(A+B)=-\frac{2t}{1-t^2}\quad$ so $t^3=3t\iff t=0$ or $t=\pm\sqrt 3$.

Thus two possibilities, the flat triangle for $0$ and the equilateral one for $+\sqrt 3$.

The last possibility is not viable ($3$ angles > $\pi/2$ sums to something > $\pi$).

*Note:*

*I gave this solution, but this is the answer for the big brutes.
You are supposed to use $\tan(x)=\tan(y)$ then $x=y+k\pi$ and deduce from there as suggested in comments, knowing that angles of a triangle are in $[0,\pi]$ (or $]0,\pi[$ for non-degenerated triangles).*